# What difference does TransactionContext make when adding an object?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, transactionscope

Does `TransactionScope` make any difference when there is just one insert in the table?

Is

```
MyObjectContext.Messages.Save( message, m => m.ID == message.ID);
MyObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

any different from

```
using( var ts = new TransactionScope() )
{
    MyObjectContext.Messages.Save( message, m => m.ID == message.ID);
    MyObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

and how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference. If you use just `SaveChanges` you still have a transaction but it has default isolation level for database server - in case of SQL server it is Read committed. If you use `TransactionScope` with default configuration you have Serialized transaction isolation level but you can change it if you use other constructor of `TransactionScope`.

So it makes a difference if you need control over transaction isolation level.

Comment: I guess this is more correct, however I'm not sure how different transaction isolation level would affect actual data. Can you can present any scenario where different code would lead to different events in the database? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't affect data. It affects what concurrent processes can do in the database. Check description of isolation levels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference.
`SaveChanges` operates within a transaction. `SaveChanges` will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty `ObjectStateEntry` objects cannot be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you are saving one item or multiple items, the use of a `TransactionScope` is redundant here.

From the [documentation for `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx):

> SaveChanges operates within a
>   transaction. SaveChanges will roll
>   back that transaction and throw an
>   exception if any of the dirty
>   ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be
>   persisted.

So you are layering on a `TransactionScope` in your example with no added benefit.

Now, if you had two separate `ObjectContext` instances with separate sets of data that you wanted to ensure that both were saved, then you would absolutely need the `TransactionScope` around both calls to `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`.